# Button that sets dropdown value onclick in Edit Form SPO 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spservices, edit-form

**INFO/OVERVIEW**

Using Sharepoint Online 2013/Classic view. The library name is **SourcesLibrary**

On the *SourcesLibrary** Edit Form, there are (3) columns:

- The dropdown column is called **Document**, which has the following choices available:

  - BackgroundReport
  - PermitRequest
- The text column is called **PeopleId** (this field is ONLY visible when the **Document** field's value is *BackgroundReport*)
- The other text column is called **contentTypeText** (upon creation of a new document, a workflow in SPD sets the value of this field to whatever the *Content Type* is -- in this case, the value of the **contentTypeText** field can either be *empty*, *BackgroundReport*, or *PermitRequest*

**MY REQUEST**

I want a button on the Edit Form that re-populates the value of the dropdown in the **Document** field. Here's a use case:

1. I open an Edit Form for a *Background Report* in the **SourcesLibrary** document library
2. The **Document** field is set to *BackgroundReport*
3. I click the button, and the **Document** dropdown field is re-set to the value *BackgroundReport*, because the **contentTypeText** field has the value *BackgroundReport*
4. As a result, the fields conditionally hidden onLoad are no longer hidden, BUT the value of the **Document** dropdown field remains *BackgroundReport*

Below is the show/hide script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.01/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.2/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// alert('onload');
// Hides Field on load
$("nobr:contains('Document')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').show();
$("nobr:contains('contentTypeText')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
$("nobr:contains('PeopleId')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
$("select[title='Document']").change(function () {
if ($("select[title='Document']").val() == "BackgroundReport") {
// If Document dropdown YES equals Background Report
$('nobr:contains("Document")').closest('tr').show();
$('nobr:contains("contentTypeText")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("PeopleId")').closest('tr').show();
} else {
// If Document dropdown NO equals Background Report
$("nobr:contains('Document')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').show();
$("nobr:contains('contentTypeText')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
$("nobr:contains('PeopleId')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance, and let me know if there's anything I can add to add clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //add button after dropdown
    $("select[title='Document']").after("<input id='resetBtn' type='button' value='Reset'/>");  
    $("#resetBtn").click(function(){
        $("select[title='Document']").val($("input[title='contentTypeText']").val());
        HideFields($("select[title='Document']").val());
    });
    // Hides Field on load    
    HideFields($("select[title='Document']").val());
    //Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
    $("select[title='Document']").change(function () {
        HideFields($(this).val());      
    });
});
function HideFields(value){
    if (value == "BackgroundReport") {
        // If Document dropdown YES equals Background Report    
        $('nobr:contains("contentTypeText")').closest('tr').hide();
        $('nobr:contains("PeopleId")').closest('tr').show();
    }else{
        // If Document dropdown NO equals Background Report 
        $("nobr:contains('contentTypeText')").closest('tr').hide();
        $("nobr:contains('PeopleId')").closest('tr').hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. I appreciate this. The code works for when the **Document** field equals "BackgroundReport". Could this code still work if there are 4 options in the **Document** dropdown (*PermitRequest* is one of them). Ideally, I was hoping that the Reset button could set the **Document** dropdown menu to match the value of the **contentTypeText** column. I make this request, because in the event we add new values to the **Document** dropdown field, I won't have to keep updating the code. Does that make sense?

Comment: I also noticed that you removed the SPServices + the other jQuery refs and the script still works! Just curious how you knew to do that.

Comment: I modify the code in the reply above, to set the Document dropdown menu to match the value of the contentTypeText column. And the code only use jQuery library, we don't need add other js libraries.

Comment: Thank you SO much. Wow. Really helped me out.